# I need a regex to find line breaks in a text area field in salesforce

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a field of type 'Text area'
With a paragraph of sentences with line breaks.it looks like this :

"test regex
for Text area

with line breaks"

The regex i used is :
([a-zA-Z0-9@.:\s*)]+\s?)*(.*?)$

Hi Martin, The scenario is.... By email to case we are getting a case created in the org.The case Descrition field contains teh sentances like :
"HI this is Case Description field
 CaseReason : test Case1
  test case 2
  test case 3"

We have to find 
"CaseReason : test Case1
  test case 2
  test case 3,"
from the whole description field context and put this value in 
the CaseReason text area field in case.

With the regex that m using we are able to find uptil CaseReason : test Case1
but not the second and third line.
Can you please help?

the complete regex we used ::
'(?m)Refer reason\s*:+\s*+([a-zA-Z0-9@.:\s*)]+\s?)*(.*?)$'

Comment: can you show us some of the code which you've attempted to use with this regex pattern?

Comment: You want to display text area text,then use split operator instead of regular expression  " textareafieldname.split('[\n\r]');    "

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the line breaks to **remove** them you could do:

```
   fieldTextArea.replaceAll('\n','');
```

If you need to **split** the content by line try this:

```
   String[] lines = fieldTextArea.split('\n');
```

If you need to remove all **non world** (letters and numbers) characters use:

```
  Pattern nonWordChar = Pattern.compile('[^\\w]');
  sw = nonWordChar.matcher(sw).replaceAll('');
```

Comment: fieldTextArea.replaceAll('\n','') -- this actually doesn't remove line breaks, though splitting works.